# In Haskell, what is the difference between using and not using let?

Tags: haskell

Someone told me Haskell does not have variables but bindings. Now what ever that means, I always wondered what the difference is when writing these bindings, like so:

```
x = 5
```

and

```
let x = 5
```

What is the difference here?

And a followup question: Am I even creating variables by doing this? If x is not a variable, what is it?

Answer (score 15):

The only real difference is where they occur.

```
-- At top (file) level or in "where" blocks, omit "let".
x = 5

f1 y = x + y
  where
    x = 5

-- Inside expressions or do-blocks, "let" is required.
f2 y = let x = 5
       in x + y

f3 y = do someAction
          let x = 5
          return (x + y)
```

In all cases, `x` is a variable.  However, you cannot change (mutate) the value of the variable.

In the GHCi prompt, it seems like you change the value of a variable, but you cannot.  You can only create new variables with the same name, the old variables still exist.

```
Prelude> let x = 3
Prelude> let f y = x + y
Prelude> let x = 10
Prelude> f 1
4
```

If you had really changed the value of `x`, then `f 1` would be 11.

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly the one I wanted to write. `let` can also appear in list/monad comprehensions.

Comment: This is what I never get. I can't change the value? If I write x = 2 and then type x ghci shows me 2. I can then just type x = 3 and type x and ghci shows me 3. So did I not just change the value of the variable x?

Comment: You created a new variable with the same name.

Comment: This is confusing, to me it looks like x is a variable now has value 3 instead of 2. So what is then mutable variables? How can you change those variables? Are you actually changing that very same place in the memory if its mutable or what?

Comment: Also, in my previous question with the x:es, if I indeed create a new variable with the same name, how do I reach both of those x:es? It seems to me I can only refer to the lastly assigned x with the value 3 but not the "old" x that has the value 2.

Comment: First question—Haskell doesn't have mutable variables.  You can create an `IORef` or an `MVar` or something but you can't create mutable variables.  Second question—if you create a new variable with the same name, you can't use the old variable any more.  If you need the old variable then don't create a new variable with the same name.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `ghci` now also lets you omit the `let`.

Comment: Successive bindings in the interactive interpreter are more like syntactic sugar for nested `let` expressions. Using the example above, it's similar to `let x = 3 in let f y = x + y in let x = 10 in f 1`. The value of `f` was fixed before you created a new variable named `x` and assigned it a value of 10, and the value of `x` when you finally call `f` comes from the scope in which `f` was *defined*, not the one in which it is *called*.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell has variables, but we say they are *bound* rather than *assigned*. These are extremely similar notions, but they differ in whether they support *multiple assignment* - Haskell does not.

```
do let x = 1
   let x = 2
   print x     -- prints "2"
```

When we say it does not, what we mean is that all variables are bound *statically*. This means that any time there's a reference to a variable, you can look back up through the code and find the *one* binding that it refers to.

Take, for example, Python, which does have multiple assignment.

```
def f(a):
    x = 1          # first assignment
    x = 2          # second assignment

    for i in a:
        x = i      # third assignment
        print x 

    print x
```

In the above example, there are three places where `x` is assigned. When we refer to `x` on the last line, we could be getting the `2` from the second assignment, or we could be getting one of the values from `a` from the assignment in the loop. Whether the third assignment took place depends on whether `a` was empty or not.

So let's look at similar code in Haskell:

```
f a = do let x = 1                    -- first binding
         let x = 2                    -- second binding
         for_ a $ \i -> do let x = i  -- third binding
                           print x
         print x
```

The final line of this output will always be "2", because at that point in the code, the second binding is the innermost binding that `x` received in that scope. If we were to introduce another closer binding, then we could change that:

```
f a = do let x = 1                    -- first binding
         let x = 2                    -- second binding
         for_ a $ \i -> do let x = i  -- third binding
                           print x
         let x = head a               -- fourth binding
         print x
```

But what we can never do is introduce *ambiguity* about *which binding* something refers to.